How do I change the css style of a TJSNode item in TMS WEB Core?
Normally when I want to change the style of a component, then I can simply do something like this in Delphi:
Panel1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('display','none');

But I want to change the style of the first element within Panel1 that has a class of Test. I can get that element using the getElementsByClassName function. The function returns a TJSHTMLCollection object which is basically an array and I can do the following to get the first item out of the array:
Panel1.ElementHandle.getElementsByClassName('Test')[0]

But that returns a TJSNode element and the TJSNode doesn't have a style on it like the ElementHandle does. So I can't do the following as that results in an error because style doesn't exist:
Panel1.ElementHandle.getElementsByClassName('Test')[0].style.setProperty('display','none');


So what can I do if I want to change the style for one of these TJSNode items in the TJSHTMLCollection object?

Okay, I just found out that I can simply cast the TJSNode to a TJSHTMLElement which is what the ElementHandle returns and then I have access to style on it:
var
  TestElem: TJSHTMLElement;
begin
  TestElem := TJSHTMLElement(Panel1.ElementHandle.getElementsByClassName('Test')[0]);
  TestElem.style.setProperty('display','none');
end;


You could have also solved that like in your previous two answers to How do I change the Tab Position in a TWebPageControl component? and ToggleButton Color Changer.

@AmigoJack Yes, but those use the asm block to do it via JavaScript. The above one is using Delphi. Just simply cast it to a TJSHTMLElement and then you have access to the style. I can actually go back to those old answers now and improve them. They don't need to use the asm block anymore.

In the other answers using JS was no problem for you and there's no indication why it should be now. Do you now understand that you've posted the same problem thrice with multiple solutions? Why not adding a second answer to one of the existing questions?
